# how get value from smartgwt Custom FilterEditorType?

Tags: filter, grid, smartgwt

I've developed a custom widget (a persian calendar consist of a base textbox & image widget on a gwt grid which look likes smartgwt calendar) & putted it in a CanvasItem because i want to add it as a filter editor for a listGrid :

ListGridField regDateTimeField = new ListGridField("regDateTime", تاریخ و زمان", 120");
regDateTimeField.setFilterEditorType(new PersianCalendarItem());

now list grid displays it successfully, but when i click on filter button, nothing happend even when it value changes.

I think i have to override some canvas item methods to return internal textbox value, but i don't know how should i do this ???

Answer (score 0):

well, we can just gess without more infos

does your filter really produce any output for the filter: what does PersianCalendarItem.getValue() return?
does the DataSource (type?) try to filter? overwrite and add logs to filterData() and fetchData()